# Would matrices of the same size upon addition be equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $P$, $Q$ and $R$ are Matrices of the same size i.e $P + R = Q + R$ then would $P = Q$?

Comment: Are the entries of $P, Q$ and $R$ complex valued?

Comment: Yes, the space of matrices forms a vector space $V$, so that $(V,+)$ is an abelian group. In every abelian group $P+R=Q+R$ implies $P-Q=0$ and hence $P=Q$.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is oddly phrased; I will assume you mean to ask

> If $P,Q,R$ are matrices of the same dimension (so that addition is defined) and satisfy $P+R = Q+R$, then does $P = Q$?

The answer is yes, as can be seen by basic algebra; for example, you can subtract $R$ from both sides of the equation and simplify.

In painful detail, all of the following equations are equivalent

- $P+R = Q+R$
- $(P+R) + (-R) = (Q+R) + (-R)$
- $P + (R + (-R)) = Q + (R + (-R))$
- $P + 0 = Q + 0$
- $P = Q$

where $0$ refers to the zero matrix of the appropriate dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because\begin{align*}P&=P+0\\&=P+(R-R)\\&=(P+R)-R\\&=(Q+R)-R\\&=Q+(R-R)\\&=Q+0\\&=Q,\end{align*}where $0$ is the null matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Denote the left side as $A$ and the right side as $B$. Then:
$$a_{ij}=p_{ij}+r_{ij} \ \ and \ \ b_{ij}=q_{ij}+r_{ij}$$
$$a_{ij}=b_{ij} \Rightarrow p_{ij}+r_{ij}=q_{ij}+r_{ij} \Rightarrow$$
$$p_{ij}+r_{ij}-r_{ij}=q_{ij} \Rightarrow$$
$$p_{ij}=q_{ij} \Rightarrow$$
$$P=Q.$$